What is causing this extrude issue in the Blender 4.0 Donut Tutorial?
I'm going through the Blender Guru tutorial series and I've run into an issue with the circle mesh. Any idea what causes this issue in the attached image?

That looks like you have some form of Snapping active (Magnet icon in the center top of the workspace). Or you are pressing Ctrl while you move them (which activates Snap even if it's not turned On)

YES! That was it! Well, at least ONE of the things I was screwing up there. Thank you so much!
